# ntexapi.rs file not working

Tags: decode

Keep getting this error involving the ntexapi.rs file:
error[E0793]: reference to packed field is unaligned. Tried to modify the code but nothing works. Files are up to date, can anyone help me out?

Comment: please provide more context. What are you trying to do, which packages, etc.

Comment: share your environment and logs if the error please.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.